# Image stuck to left

Tags: html, css

Okay so this is a subscription box with fancybox that I'm making and everything is going well.
Just a little problem here.
the image that I'm using is stuck to the left and even margin property is of no use.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image:url(../../images/subscribe.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:left bottom;
        margin-bottom:85px;
        line-height:2px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;

    }
    #h1_1 {

        something;

    }
    #h1_2 {
        something;
    }
    #h1_3 {
        something;

    }

/*
    #img1_1 {
        background-position:left bottom;
        margin:0px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;

    }
    */

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <p id="h1_1">
        <b>Subscribe Us</b>
        <br>
        <p id="h1_2"> Sometext</p><!-- end h1_2 -->

        <p id="h1_3"> sometext</p><!-- end h1_3 -->
        </p> <!-- end h1_1 -->

     <!--   <img src="../../images/subscribe.png" id="img1_1">  -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

If the margin propety is applied the whole body gets shifted
and if i don't put the image in the background, creatig  in the body, this way i can't write the exact text right besides the image.

Comment: can you please attach a screen shot ?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bune_dev13/wk99d/1/
the image gets stuck somewhere just below the sometext2 on the extremel left side. How so ever i tried, nothings happening :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this gets you in the right direction:

if you use the img tag then this should work

```
#img1_1 {
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
```

if you use the background-image you should use background position:

```
body {
    background-position: 20px 20px;
}
```

No offence, but I recommend you further dive into CSS and HTML, because this is a pretty basic CSS question.

Comment: requires 15 reputations to vote and i don't have that much . sorry man.